# deserialize Json file to java Object that contains a map with an object as key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am struggling to find a way to read a json file that need to fit into a Map. 
So, I have a class ingredients that only contains a String variable ingredient. In another class that is called Recipe I have a Map   that will track the ingredients and the amount needed for that particular recipe and a String for the name of the Recipe.

```
public class Recipe implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private Map<Ingredients,Integer> ingredientsList = new HashMap<>();

    public Recipe() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map<Ingredients, Integer> getIngredientsList() {
        return ingredientsList;
    }

    public void setIngredientsList(Map<Ingredients, Integer> ingredientsList) {
        this.ingredientsList = ingredientsList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Recipe{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", ingredientsList=" + ingredientsList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I have a testClass  that contains two methods one to write my recipe to a json file and one to read It from the same json file

```
@Test
    public void writeToJsonFile(){
        Ingredients pasta = new Ingredients();
        pasta.setName("pasta");
        Ingredients bolognaise = new Ingredients();
        bolognaise.setName("bolognaise");

        Map<Ingredients,Integer>ingredientsIntegerMap = new HashMap<>();
        ingredientsIntegerMap.put(pasta,500);
        ingredientsIntegerMap.put(bolognaise,600);

        Recipe spaghetti = new Recipe();
        spaghetti.setName("spaghetti");
        spaghetti.setIngredientsList(ingredientsIntegerMap);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/test/resources/recipe1.json");
            writer.write(gson.toJson(spaghetti));
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void readFromJsonFile(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/test/resources/recipe1.json"));
            Recipe dish =gson.fromJson(buffer, Recipe.class);
            System.out.println(dish);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now my issue is the following when I create a recipe that contains some ingredient and save it to a json fill I don’t have any issue everything works but when I want to load the created Jason file to a recipe it doesn’t work.

this is the error message i get when i try to read the Json file

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 4 column 6 path $.ingredientsList.
```

Here the Created Json file that contain the recipe

```
{
  "name":"spaghetti",
  "ingredientsList":{
    "Ingredients{name\u003d\u0027pasta\u0027}":500,
    "Ingredients{name\u003d\u0027bolognaise\u0027}":600
  }
}
```

the issue occur due to the Map in the Recipe Class when i remove it or replace it by a List everything works but i would like to use a Map.

can someone help on this issue or recommend another way to track the amount of ingredient for a recipe

thanks

Comment: So I'm guessing "Ingredients{name ..." isn't a valid JSON name?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit weird that you put as a key in Map an Object that doesn't contain any unique identifier. Maybe it will be better to change Ingredients class to an enum like the following:

```
public enum Ingredients {
    PASTA,
    BOLOGNAISE
}
```

Your JSON will change to:

```
{
  "name":"spaghetti",
  "ingredientsList":{
    "PASTA":500,
    "BOLOGNAISE":600
  }
}
```

Or create an aggregate Object like:

```
public class IngredientQuantity {

    private Ingredient ingredient;
    private double quantity;

}

class Ingredient {
    private String name;
}
```

And then replace your map with a simple list:

```
{
  "name": "spaghetti",
  "ingredientsList": [
    {
      "ingredient": {
        "name": "PASTA"
      },
      "quantity": 500
    },
    {
      "ingredient": {
        "name": "BOLOGNAISE"
      },
      "quantity": 600
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply the goals is to expand it later with a connection to a database, were the user can add new ingredients and those ingredient will also containt the quantity on hands.

Comment: so maybe it's not necessary to keep these objects in the map? what comes to my mind is to create an aggregate Object like `IngredientWeight` with `Ingredients` and `quantity`: `"ingredientsList":[{"ingredients": "...", "quantity": 500},{"ingredients": "...", "quantity": 500},]`

Comment: thanks again for the response i think i will go the way that you suggest by creating an aggregate object. when i will have more experience with converting Json to java object il will find out how to use the maps with objects inside..